# How to make `<div>` not expand when `<input>` is hovered

Tags: html, css

### Code

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 14px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.topnav input[type=text]:hover {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu' class='topnav'>
  <a href='#1'>abcdefg</a>
  <a href='#2'>abcdefg</a>
  <a href='#3'>abcdefg</a>
  <a href='#4'>abcdefg</a>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Search here'>
</div>
```

### Goal

As you can see, when `<input>` is hovered, its border expands by 3 pixels.

However, it makes `<div>` expand as well, which is not what I want. In other words, I want `<div>` not to expand when `input` is being hovered.

### What I've tried

To accomplish the above, I've set the width of `<input>` and `<a>` to `auto`

> As long as the value of width is auto, the element can have horizontal margin, padding and border without becoming wider than its container (unless of course the sum of margin-left + border-left-width + padding-left + padding-right + border-right-width + margin-right is larger than the container). The width of its content box will be whatever is left when the margin, padding and border have been subtracted from the container’s width.

Recovered from [The difference between width:auto and width:100%](https://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/)

Unfortunately, It didn't work. I also don't want to use fixed widths, for example, set `<input>` width to 20 pixels. Although it works, that is, it doesn't make `<div>` expand, it's too small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple add transparent border on default state.

```
border: 3px solid blue;
```

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  display: inline-block;

  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 14px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.1s;
border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.topnav input[type=text]:hover {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu' class='topnav'>
  <a href='#1'>abcdefg</a>
  <a href='#2'>abcdefg</a>
  <a href='#3'>abcdefg</a>
  <a href='#4'>abcdefg</a>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Search here'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add a transparent border like `border: 3px solid transparent` to the `<input>` elements initial style so space from the `border` is already allocated in the parent container for it and therefore doesn't make `.topnav` grow when the `<input>` is hovered.

The user agent stylesheet provides a default 2px `border-width` for input elements so when you try using `width: auto` and make the hover state `border: 3px solid blue`, we are seeing the border go from 2px to 3px and the parent container `.topnav` growing with it due to the `<input>` elements border increasing and occupying more space.

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 14px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.1s;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.topnav input[type=text]:hover {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu' class='topnav'>
  <a href='#1'>abcdefg</a>
  <a href='#2'>abcdefg</a>
  <a href='#3'>abcdefg</a>
  <a href='#4'>abcdefg</a>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Search here'>
</div>
```

Comment: @Nameless Does this help answer your question?

Comment: @Nameless Yes It does. It's simpler than I expected and it works. However, I'm keen to know why setting the width to `auto` does not work.

Comment: because height is still changing. also by default input elements have 2px border.

Comment: @TannerDolby to Nameless

Comment: @Nameless Was there a reason my answer wasn't accepted? Too lengthy?

Comment: @TannerDolby You were second by some seconds. Plus, you have a higher rep than him but your answer is good.

Comment: @Nameless Ah I see, makes sense. Also see my updated answer for more on why `width: auto` doesn't work. Hopefully that helps.